# Can you define names for dates in Excel to use them in formulas?

Tags: excel

I hope you are all well.

I have a question. I have a list with many payments listed on column A with dates (format day/month/year) in column B and I would like to use a formula which says something like

```
IF= A1 = Q2, "pay", "don't pay" , IF= A2 = Q2, "pay", "don't pay"...
```

Q2 means quarter 2

Could I define names for dates? For example Q2 would be 01/04/2021 - 30/06/2021 so all the dates within that range would be named Q2.

Best regards

Comment: You could use a lookup table for the dates of each quarter and use `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` to see what quarter a given date is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try anyone of the approaches as explained below, the first one is using `ROUNDUP` & `MONTH` Function and the other one is using `DEFINED NAMES`.

**First Approach ---> Using ROUNDUP & MONTH FUNCTION**

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
="Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A3)/3,0)
```

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=IF("Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A3)/3,0)="Q2","Pay","Don't Pay")
```

So you can see i have used two columns in the first approach just to make it understandable, therefore just wrap the formula in cell `B3` within an IF logic as shown in cell `C3` to get the desired output.

**Second Approach --> Using DEFINED NAMES & SUMPRODUCT FUNCTION**

• Formula used in Defined Names

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(--TEXT("01-04-2021","dd/mm/yyyy")&":"&--TEXT("30-06-2021","dd/mm/yyyy")))
```

[image: DEFINED NAMES Q2]

So you can see I have Defined the Quarter 2 as `_Q2` and the reason is a name must either begin with a **letter**, **underscore (_)**, or **backslash ()**. If a name begins with anything else, Excel will throws an **error**.

Therefore the formula used in cell `D3`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3>=_Q2)*(A3<=_Q2))
```

The above formula creates an array of `TRUE's & FALSE's` and multiplies to return the corresponding values.

Now the above formula when wrapped within an IF Function it gives us the requisite output as desired,

Formula used in cell `E3` (Same it can be done in one cell, to make it understandable i have used two columns)

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A3>=_Q2)*(A3<=_Q2))=1,"Pay","Don't Pay")
```

So this is how you can used a Defined names for dates in excel and then use the same within a formula.

[image: DEFINED_NAMES_FOR_DATES]

Comment: Many thanks, I think the first option is the easiest one. However, the second approach could be considered the more professional one as I believe that working with assigned names is very efficient and professional in terms of presentation. I also have a question could you also use IF and AND to determine if a date falls under a quarter? E.g  IF (01/04/2021) = AND (01/04/2021), (30/06/2021), "Q2", "Other Q")) I am getting an error. Does it happen because I would have to assign Q2 to this range. Ie. Q2 = (01/04/2021 - 30/06/2021)? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the operators - - for? =ROW(INDIRECT(--TEXT("01-04-2021","dd/mm/yyyy")&":"&--TEXT("30-06-2021","dd/mm/yyyy")))

Comment: @viewotst sorry for the delay in response, i wasn't well, ok, so -- double minus is used to change a textual number to actual numbers. if you select the whole and press F9 you will see it creates an array of TRUE's & FALSE's

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not provide names for dates but it might meet your needs:

Make sure column A is formatted as a date, then use this formula to get the quarter from the month (this array allows you to set Q1 if it is not the same as calendar quarters):

```
="Q"&CHOOSE(MONTH(A1),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
```

Then test the value of this column:

```
=if(C1="Q1", "Pay", "Do not Pay")
```

You could also create a cell at the top of your spreadsheet and name it current_quarter.  Then you would type in the current quarter "Q1", "Q2", ... and your formula would be

```
=if(C1= current_quarter, "Pay", "Do Not Pay")
```

Comment: Thanks Donald, can you please explain the arguments of your first formula? Why the 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s?

Comment: Each number represents a quarter. If you are on a calendar quarter, you would use the arguments above.  But let's say your first quarter starts in APRIL, then your array would be :  Month(A1), 4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3  and so on.

Comment: Hi Donald, thank you for the answer. So for example if my date is 01/08/2021 and then I use the formula = "Q"&CHOOSE(MONTH(A8),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4). I understand that the choose function is going to count 8 positions so it will return the number 3 which is correct as August falls in the third quarter. I also understand if the first quarter starts in April but how would you reason it if it started in another month for example September? Would you do Month(A1), 2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3? Sorry I don´t understand the reasoning.

Comment: If your fiscal calendar is the same as the regular calendar, you always use the above formula.  Companies, like Microsoft, are on a fiscal calendar that starts on July 1.  So they would use 333,444,111,222.

Answer (score 0):

You are using standard calendar month quarters, so we can get the quarter number easily by dividing and rounding up.

```
=ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0)
```

You can then use this number in your IF function.

```
=IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0)=2,"Pay","Don't Pay")
```

Comment: Thank you Jody. Just out of curiosity, how would we do it if we wanted to get the semesters? If we divide the month / 2 we don't get it. For instance, 01/04/2021/ 2 = 2. April is in the first semester, not in the second one. Thanks

Comment: @viewotst Assuming there are two semesters in a year, you would divide by 6.  You essentially divide by how many months make up your grouping.  3 months in a quarter, divide by 3.  6 months in a semester, divide by 6.